# How do I get cmd to ‘combine’ multiple files from a windows backup?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to extract a .pst file from a windows backup. In order to do this I need to copy each ‘partial’ file from the backup zips and then combine them together to make the one file. I have a command that will copy them out and combine them from [this post](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/174270-backup-manually-extract-files-vista-windows-7-a.html) but the problem I have is that cmd is not doing it in numerical order, therefore the file is not complete. I am using this script to put the files in order:

```
Echo y | for /F "tokens=*" %A in (filenamesinorder.txt) do copy /b %A “c:\pstcombiner\combined.pst”
```

But all this does is copy each individual file and overwrites it. I get that that’s what the command does but I need it to combine all the files into one. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Form the [Microsoft documentation for the copy command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy):

> To append files, specify a single file for destination, but multiple files for source (use wildcard characters or file1+file2+file3 format).

You’ll need to construct the source text for the copy in your for loop and do the copy after; I’ll see if I can provide an example when I am at my Windows system.

Comment: I tried file1 + file2 etc but it doesn’t work after file47…

Comment: That sounds like a limitation in cmd. You will have to create a series of intermediate files and concatenate them the same way

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating, you could try merging using the `type` command:

create an empty target file

```
copy nul target.ext > nul
```

then loop the `type` command to merge the files to the end of the target file

```
type fileN.ext>>target.ext
```

where fileN.ext is file 1, 2,3 ... *n*